# Why isn't money updating?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code:

```html
<span id="money"></span> money
<button style="background: green; color: white" onclick="money++">add money</button>
<script>
  var moneyEl = document.querySelector("#money")
 var money = 100
 moneyEl.innerText = money
</script>
```

When "add money" is clicked #money isnt updating. Sorry for my bad english...

Comment: You need to put your JS in a function and call the function onclick. Otherwise the code gets run only once, when the page loads.

Comment: It's not like you established a connection between `#money`'s `innerText` and the variable `money`. The value of `money` got assigned to `innerText` exactly once, and ***the current value of `money` at that time*** was assigned. Incrementing `money++` afterwards doesn't repeat that assignment nor keep the `innerText` in sync.

Answer (score 1):

Money isn't updating because the onclick event just increments the variable money and does nothing to the html element. If you want to increment the html element, something like this is needed:

```
<span id="money"></span> money
<button style="background: green; color: white" onclick="addMoney()">add money</button>
<script>
  var moneyEl = document.querySelector("#money");
    var money = 100;
    moneyEl.innerText = money;
 function addMoney(){
    document.querySelector("#money").innerText = Number(document.querySelector("#money").innerText) + 1;
 }
</script>
```